# User profile pictures in Laravel, Non-object error

Tags: laravel

I am trying to allow users to upload profile photo using laravel. When I run the dp() function on my user model I get the non-object error. 
My user model:
```

```
public function dp()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Blog\models\Dp', 'user_id');
    }
    public function getDp()
    {
        if (!$this->dp()){
            return 'public/image/standard_dp.jpg';
        }
        return $this->dp()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc' )->first()->url;
    }
```

```
The error is supposedly in the second to last line of this code, but when I run a dd, instead of a return there is no error.
Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm guessing the `first()` call returned a non-object. Try `dd($this->dp()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc' )->first())` and see what it says.

Comment: You can also use `firstOrFail()` to debug

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `getDp()` method with this:

```
public function getDp()
{
    if ($this->dp->isEmpty()) {
        return 'public/image/standard_dp.jpg';
    }

    return $this->dp->sortByDesc('created_at')->first()->url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the isEmpty() and sortByDesc() functions threw errors

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I replaced the getDp() function with the following:

```
     public function getDp()
{
    if ($this->dp()->count()===0)
    {
        return 'public/image/standard_dp.jpg';
    }
    return $this->dp()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc' )->first()->url;
}
```